# PayPal chained payments using Website Payments Pro (or similar)

Tags: paypal

I am researching building a marketplace-type site where users can create their own stores and I would take a percent of the sale. This is possible using Paypal's chained payments, but from their documentation, it appears this requires using a modal box of Paypal's site and form. Is there any way to process chained payments with something like their Website Payments Pro, which would allow users to remain on the same site the whole time? I feel this would look more professional.

Alternately, if there is a non-PayPal service that can do this, please let me know.

Comment: As for PayPal: no. Website Payments Pro and Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution don't do chained payments, and the products that do chained payments (Adaptive Payments) includes the web flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using an alternative to Chained Payments?  Could you manage that business logic from your backend instead and initiate multiple API-driven Payments Pro transactions?