# Paypal Adaptive chained payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-nvp

Hi I'm a little confusing with this adpative payments option, what I have is this scenario.

I have a site which can charge without problem using paypal api nvp using credit card directly.

what I want to do is charge in the same way with the credit card and then, split the income into two differents paypal accounts. 15% in one and the rest in the other one.

So how can do this? I can't find any example for achieve this, Im watched a few examples of adaptive payment where the sender (which use an paypal account) send money to the primary reciever and then this keep his fee and the transfer the rest. But not using a credit card as an input of payment

But what I want to do is charge with the credit card. Keep 15% fee and the send the rest to the other account. what I want is only be charge with 1 fee from paypal and not two from transfer money to two differentes accounts.

I just need an example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your scenario correctly, but I'm using chained payments to process a payment to a primary receiver, and then charge that receiver 3% to go towards my site's account. I'm using C# language and NVP, and this is what I have:

```
    double mysiteAmt = Convert.ToDouble(payPalObj.transactionAmt) * .03;
    // receiver(0) is the primary receiver of the payment
    body.Append("receiverList.receiver(0).amount=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(payPalObj.transactionAmt.ToString()));
    body.Append("&");
    body.Append("receiverList.receiver(0).email=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(payPalObj.receiverEmailAcct));
    body.Append("&");
    body.Append("receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true");
    body.Append("&");
    // receiver(1) is my site
    body.Append("receiverList.receiver(1).amount=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(mysiteAmt.ToString()));
    body.Append("&");
    body.Append("receiverList.receiver(1).email=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("payments@mysite.com")); // This is my site's PayPal account
    body.Append("&");
    body.Append("receiverList.receiver(1).primary=false");
```

When the sender is redirected to PayPal, they only see one transaction amount. When the payment is processed and the primary receiver logs in to PayPal, they will see two transactions: 1) A payment FROM the sender, and 2) a payment TO my site's PayPal account.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

You also have to include this so that the primary receiver is responsible for the PayPal fees.

```
    body.Append("feesPayer=PRIMARYRECEIVER"); // Receiver will pay the fees.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. But in my scenario where I'm usign "payment pro" to process the money input (chargin the credit card user without paying with a paypal account), what do I have to do? to making work, I mean in you example where goes the credit card payment? or this is after you charge the credit card user? and with the money in you account transfer and split this amount..?

Comment: Ah, OK, I see. The person paying in your scenario doesn't have a PayPal account. I'm using the Adaptive Payments API, and in my scenario the sender (the person paying), the receiver, and my site all have PayPal accounts. In one of the scenarios I used to test, the sender had a PayPal account with their credit card linked to the account. When they processed the transaction, it charged their credit card.

I do not believe PayPal Payments Pro supports chained payments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690007/paypal-chained-payments-using-website-payments-pro-or-similar

Comment: mmmm I see... damn it... :P, I just start a ticket in paypal to see if they know some alternative to my case, I guess I will have to change all!!! the flow of my app which is already finish :( ... Thanks for the support man.